# Please assist me in identifying this font on a Postcard product

Tags: fonts, font-identification

[image: Where it says "PANTONE" and if its the same as where it says "100 Postcards"]

What's the font where it says "PANTONE"? Is the font of "100 Postcards"the same? If not, what is it?

Comment: Are you only asking if the 2 sets of text are the same font or what the font is?

Answer (score 1):

All is Helvetica Bold. See the InDesign screenshot. Here's the same text recreated and a straightened version of your photo.

[image]

In the InDesign screenshot the character specs are just ater placing the registered trademark symbol.

NOTE: If you type the text and select the font, the result is far away from the one in your photo. There's reduced line spacing and the kerning is on. The kerning mode = optical. Without it many characters must be placed manually.

Answer (score 0):

Helvetica Neue on the outside and on the 100 postcards.